# How should an iOS library handle logging to a file on iPhone's file system?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS library project and need to create an API that takes an NSString parameter which is a path, and the library will write some debugging messages to a file in that path.

I've done some research about logging onto a file in iPhone's file system, one approach is using

```
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

This will redirect any following NSLog to a file...

While this seems easy, I have a question: Will this also redirect the API consumer's application(calling application)'s NSLog to the file? I don't want this behavior because I want to be able to control what goes in there as a library..

If that is the behavior, what other approach I can use to achieve my requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the desired functionality is to pass a path and write some debugging info to a file on that path? If that is so, I don't think you should redirect all your `NSLog` calls to a file; just using the `NSString writeToFile:` would be enough:

```
-(void)writeToFile:(NSString*)path {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *myMessage="This is the data to write to the file";    
    [myMessage writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
}
```

If you want to append to that file, you can use the `NSFileHandle` functionality - check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilehandle).